# Is it possible to force a Wix Bootstrapper/MSI to display the Install Screen even if it is already installed?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, multiple-instances, bootstrapper

I have a Wix Bootstrapper which is used to install various MSIs, one of which may need to be installed with multiple instances on the same machine. I currently am telling it which MSIs to install via command line parameters. When I try and install the second software, however, either via the bootstrapper or the MSI, I get the "Software already installed, repair or uninstall" GUI. I want to be able to install the software twice in different locations.

I have set up the following to attempt to get this working in the MSI:

```
<InstanceTransforms Property="INSTANCEID">
  <Instance Id="I01" ProductCode="{7C382908-0072-4CF2-8C5D-A7B7F5E09DD8}" ProductName="Software2"/>
</InstanceTransforms>
```

and when trying to do this, pass the Bootstrapper (which then passes to the MSI)

MSINEWINSTANCE = 1
TRANSFORMS = I01